# Fenchel conjugate of the following function.

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, duality-theorems

What should be closed form for $\iota_C^{\star}(\mathbf{u})$ if $C$ is closed and bounded and convex?
($\iota_C(x)=0$ for $x\in C$ and $\infty$ otherwise).

And if $f$ is closed and convex, can $\min_{\mathbf{u}} f^{\star}(\mathbf{u}) +\iota_C^{\star}(\mathbf{u})$ be further simplified. Thank you.

Comment: the answer depends on $f$ and $C$

Comment: @LinAlg. So do you mean that the expression cannot be further simplified?

Comment: correct, unless you specify $f$ and $C$

Comment: @LinAlg Ok, thank you very much.

Comment: Maybe not too useful, but for the last part, you can express in terms of [infimal convolutions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_conjugate#Infimal_convolution): $f^* + \iota_C^{\star} = (f\operatorname{\Box} \iota_C)^*$

Comment: @p.s. I think we can indeed simplify the expression into a minimax problem by calculating the Fenchel conjugate of the indicator function when $C$ is convex, could you simplified it into a $\sup$ of something, it is probably something like polar operator/supporttng function.